# ComponentArt Grid Unlicensed control. Click here for more information

Tags: sitecore-client

I'm using Sitecore 8.2 Update 5. I do have ComponentArt Grid license file under bin folder. What else may be the reason of this error? It's working fine locally. I see suggestions to add ComponentArt Grid license file in bin folder which is not my case.

[image]

Comment: Have you done recently upgrade? If yes, download Sitecore installation zip package and take this lic file from there to your bin folder. That should do the trick. This lic file is different between Sitecore versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if you have `ComponentArt.UIFramework.lic` file in the bin folder. It is bundled with the Sitecore Installation itself. But as Peter said if you upgraded your project than take it from vanilla Sitecore installation specific to your version. Also check the permissions on the license file, if it is already there.

Answer (score 3):

If this doesn't solve your issue and your site is FIPS compliant, Sitecore has a machine.config update referenced here: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/enable_fips, and also detailed here: [Sitecore 8.2 Update 6 ComponentArt Unlicensed Control](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/sitecore-8-2-update-6-componentart-unlicensed-control).

Answer (score 0):

If 1st and 2nd answer don't work for you, please download ZIP archive of the Sitecore site root folder and replace Sitecore folder and DLLs in your solution. It should resolve this problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Along with licence file you have to do following thing..

Are you integrating GSP into an existing site? If so, then make sure this is in your global.asax file:

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{

  Application[ComponentArtWebUI_AppKey] = "This edition of ComponentArt Web.UI is licensed for Gallery Server Pro application only.";

}
```

If you are using GSP as a standalong app, then you shouldn’t be getting that message.